# Trouble getting results from SearchView with Listview using Custom Adapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-studio, searchview

I have a Listview with a Custom BaseAdapter. I have already done the code for my MainActivity.java to apply SearchView. However, I have problem with the performFiltering method in my Adapter class due to the reason that I have a ImageView that would be shown on my ListView. The ImageView is originally in the form of String because I would like to get the image from an url in my Firebase Storage and then convert it to Image by using the Picasso library.
TL:DR. My problem is that everytime I perform a search, the url of the image stored in Firebase is showing up instead of the actual Image. Help is appreciated thanks.

Below is my Adapter Class:

```
public class GridAdapter extends BaseAdapter implements Filterable {

CustomFilter mCustomFilter;
ArrayList<GridItem> filterList;
private Context mContext;
private ArrayList<GridItem> gtem;

//Constructor


public GridAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList<GridItem> gtem) {
    this.filterList = gtem;
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.gtem = gtem;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return gtem.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return gtem.get(position);
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    View v = View.inflate(mContext,R.layout.grid_item, null);
    ImageView putPic = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.imageHere);
    TextView putTitle = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.titleHere);
    TextView putPrice = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.per_price);
    TextView putCountry = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.countryHere);


    //
    putCountry.setText("Country: " + gtem.get(position).getCountry());
    putTitle.setText(gtem.get(position).getmTitleHere());
    putCountry.setText(gtem.get(position).getCountry());
    putPrice.setText("Price: " + "$" + gtem.get(position).getmPriceHere());
    Picasso.with(mContext).load(gtem.get(position).getmImageView()).resize(450 , 500).into(putPic);


    return v;
}



@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    //To-do Auto-generated method stub
    if (mCustomFilter == null )
    {
        mCustomFilter = new CustomFilter();
    }

    return mCustomFilter;
}

//Inner Class
class CustomFilter extends Filter
{

    @Override
    protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {

        FilterResults results = new FilterResults();
        if (constraint != null && constraint.length()>0)
        {
            //Constraint to Upper
            constraint = constraint.toString().toUpperCase();

            ArrayList<GridItem> filters = new ArrayList<GridItem>();

            //to get specific items
            for (int i = 0; i<filterList.size(); i++)
            {
                if (filterList.get(i).getmTitleHere().toUpperCase().contains(constraint))
                {
                    GridItem g = new GridItem(filterList.get(i).getmTitleHere() , filterList.get(i).getmPriceHere(), filterList.get(i).getmImageView()
                    , filterList.get(i).getCountry());

                    filters.add(g);
                }
            }
            results.count = filters.size();
            results.values = filters;

        }else {
            results.count = filterList.size();
            results.values = filterList;
        }
        return results;
    }

    @Override
    protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {

        gtem = (ArrayList<GridItem>) results.values;
        notifyDataSetChanged();


    }
}
}
```

Comment: use [this](https://gist.github.com/pskink/2dd4d17a93caf02ff696533e82f952b0) generic `Filterable` adapter and override its `matches()` method

Comment: Sry I'm quite new to this. I don't quite understand the generic Filterable adapter sorry @pskink

Comment: just use it as a base class instead of `BaseAdapter` - `class GridAdapter extends MatchableArrayAdapter<GridItem> {...`

Comment: sorry how do i do that? I really have no clue how sorry @pskink

Comment: all you have to do is to override just two methods: `matches` and `onBind`

Comment: sorry i really don't know how to do that. do you have any examples? @pskink

Comment: no, i dont have any